# A better way to write CSS for a list

Tags: css

I'm writing CSS for a navigation/list and I want to stagger the list items out 5px for every sub level and I started to write:

```
    .panel ul li ul li a { padding:6px 0 6px 20px !important; background-color:#333; background-position:10px center; }
    .panel ul li ul li ul li a { padding:6px 0 6px 25px !important; background-color:#444; background-position:15px center; }
    .panel ul li ul li ul li ul li a { padding:6px 0 6px 30px !important; background-color:#555; background-position:20px center; }
    .panel ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a { padding:6px 0 6px 35px !important; background-color:#666; background-position:25px center; }
    .panel ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li ul li a { padding:6px 0 6px 40px !important; background-color:#777; background-position:30px center; }
```

And thought "this is ridiculous there must be a better way" something that would possibly keep indenting no matter how many levels.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this the purpose of the nested list?  The padding on the `<ul>` is there without any styles...http://jsbin.com/AcukOxuF/1/edit.  Do you have an image of how you want it?

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS there's no real better way to do that. I recommend using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), with lets you write CSS in nested form, e.g.

```
.panel {
    ul {
        li {
            a {
                padding:6px 0px 6px 20px;
            }
            ul {
                li {
                    a{...}
                } 
            }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Anything in CSS3 that can help? I don't need to support older browsers

Comment: I was thinking that maybe you could use nth-child or whatever, but that doesn't apply to nested elements. As far as I'm aware there aren't any CSS3 selectors that would help you here. You could also apply these styles programmatically with JavaScript; that might be a better option since it seems like there's a pattern.

Comment: Re-read your question - what you are trying to accomplish? Nested lists are automatically indented, no need to have CSS do that.

Comment: Good point, the websites "reset" css strips all that out, might be best to venture down the jQuery road, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jquery is the key :)
didnt try the code below. but it should look similar to this.

```
$('.panel li').each( function(){
var myPadding = $(this).parent.css('padding') + 5;
$(this).css('padding' , myPadding );})
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, yeah there will possibly be more than one li per level as its a menu generated by a CMS

Comment: still jquery is the key. im using 'each' it will loop for all li inside the div panel with any levels